# Will re-purchasing audiobooks on iTunes charge me again?

Tags: itunes-store

I have purchased audiobooks on iTunes and can't re-download them. I try in iTunes but it asks if I want to buy it again. Will I be charged again for the books I already paid for?

Comment: If it's exactly the same product, iTunes will never charge you again. But actually why can't you re-download it ?

Comment: Make sure you are trying to re-download them using the same iTunes account as was used for purchasing. You can also check your purchase history. You can verify it by logging into iTunes and clicking Purchased under Quick Links. If you see them there, you are not going to get charged again. Worst case scenario, you can always open a dispute with Apple and they are usually pretty good at reversing wrong charges.